# Load Testing of MEAN applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, load-testing, mean-stack

I am currently writing an application with the `MEAN stack` and just deployed the first version to a server. The application consists of a `static HTML file` (and `CSS` and some images additionally) and a whole bunch of `JavaScript` files. A lot of the JS is executed when loading the page, including several requests from the `Angular` application to the `NodeJS` server.

I have tried several load testing tools ([Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest)) so far, but they only test the server against serving the `static HTML file`. I would need a tool (or options for the above tools) that would run at least the init part of the JavaScript. I know that this will require at least some small browser simulation or any other approach to test run the JS of the html file. Any pointers in the right directions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: JMeter should be enough. 
You can configure JMeter to concurrently request pages, load embedded resources and make calls to your API.

Comment: @DrewR thanks for the answer, just one question: my understanding of JMeter is, that it only fetches the html files (and everything attached to it like the JS files). How can I configure it to run the JS code? Or do you mean I have to specify all requests that my JS code would do in JMeter by hand?

Comment: Yes you need to craft the requests that would be executed by your JS in JMeter. 
Otherwise you probably want a end to end test framework that can simulate a browser session (headless browser)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com/) to test a similar application (AngularJS front-end that communicates with the back-end using web-services).

When recording the scenario, the script will contain retrieving the static resources (like you've already done) but will also contain the dynamic http requests which go to the back-end (NodeJS in your app).

Although the JavaScript code is actually executed, the requests that affect the server are recorded and performed.

From the server's point of view, that's all that matters. The server doesn't 'know' (or care) about what the client is doing - it does not affect it's work-load so it's not important to simulate in load-testing. Using a full (or headless) browser (like, say, Selenium) is usually an overkill in load-testing - it doesn't scale well, require a lot of resources and therefore not efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your thought to using (headless) browsers for load testing is exactly what prevented my from going in that direction so far. Furthermore, the HTML on my website is rather complex since it features a big map. I am retrieving (geo) information from various sources and only some requests target my NodeJS installation to test. If I test this scenario with massed (headless) browsers, I test the other sources and the client rendering as well, which is of no real interest to me atm. Thanks for the input again, I'll check out WebLOAD.